# Using Appium and Python for Test Automation with "contains"

Tags: python, windows, automated-tests, appium

I'm working in test automation using Appium.  This will run on a Windows machine, and we're using python to drive Appium.
I'm able to find the main window for the application that I'm automating using:

`ApplicationWindow = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//Pane[@ClassName='wcl_manager1']")`

Then I need to search that ApplicationWindow for the button I need to press.  I only know that the button will include certain text, but will have other text too.  If I knew for sure what the text would be, then I could do:

`MenuButton = ApplicationWindow.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@Name='Hub window']")`

but of course I can't.

I've looked through xpath documentation, and figure that the 'contains' part is what I need, but for the life of me I can't get the syntax right.

I've tried multiple options in syntax:

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[contains(name(), 'Hub']")
find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[contains(@Name='Hub']")
find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[contains(@Name, 'Hub']")
```

but none seem to be the magic bullet.

Can anyone point me to the right syntax for Python and Appium's "contains" functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Android I use in my `elements.yml` file

```
android_hamburger_menu_my_shiny_btn:
  locator: xpath
  selector: //android.widget.Button[contains(@text, 'My Partial Text Here')]
```

And for iOS:

```
ios_hamburger_menu_my_shiny_btn:
  locator: xpath
  selector: //*[contains(@name, "My Partial Text Here")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was going on up in my question.  I did a bunch of testing and found that this is the proper way:

`MenuButton = ApplicationWindow.find_elements_by_xpath("//TreeItem[contains(@Name, 'Harry')]")`

which looks exactly like one of the things I tried up above.